# Supervisor on Heroku

Tags: heroku, supervisord, beanstalkd

I use a remote server to process beanstalkd queues that I would like to use on my application running on Heroku. Is there any way to run [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to monitor that the queue command (Laravel: `php artisan queue:listen`) is running?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: what's the reason why you want to use supervisord here? 

In the heroku-world your queue command would be another process type in your `Procfile` and would be watched by heroku